# Replace comma with space after each 3 strings

Tags: mysql, regex, csv, sed

I have a csv file like the follwing:

```
"user1","track1","player1","user1","track2","player2","user1","track3","player3",........
```

what I need to do is to replace a comma with space (NOT all the commas), only those commas after playerIds (to specify a line so I could import them later to Mysql). So, I need the result be like this:

```
"user1","track1","player1" "user1","track2","player2" "user1","track3","player3" ........
```

I found that we can replace a comma with space with [sed](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/152251-replace-comma-blank-space-using-sed.html):

```
sed 's/,/ /g' output.csv >output2.csv
```

however, it replace all commas with space.. I don't know how to do it only after each 3 strings. any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` like this:

```
sed -E 's/(([^,]*,){2}[^,]*),/\1 /g' file

"user1","track1","player1" "user1","track2","player2" "user1","track3","player3"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply..but it didn't work :( the output now is like `"user1","track1","player1”,”user1","track2","player2”,”user1","track3","player3"`

Comment: I have included output sed command is giving in my answer. Is it not the one you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, but it's strange since when I write your command, the output for me is different... This is the uotput I get after running your command: `"user1","track1","player1”,”user1","track2","player2”,”user1","track3","player3‌​" ` :|

Comment: ok, it shows me this output: `"user1","track1","player1" "user1","track2","player2" "user1","track3","player3"` .. BUT, it is not changed inside the file, could u pls tell me how could I change it inside the file ?

Comment: thank you! I could also change the file with just adding this: `file >file2`

Comment: Using this `sed`: `sed -i.bak -E 's/(([^,]*,){2}[^,]*),/\1 /g' file`